# cannot add reanimated library with mmkv storage library

Tags: java, android, react-native, mobile

I am attempting to add react native reanimated library but I cannot add it as I already have mmkv library.

The issue is that the installation steps for reanimated is to add this code in MainApplication.java

```
@Override
      protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
        return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
      }
```

this is problematic because in my file JSIModule package exists already for mmkv installation

```
                @Override
                protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
                    return new RNMMKVJSIModulePackage();
                }
```

my issue is that I am unsure how to return both mmkv and reanimated libraries in the function. When attempting to have both functions, the app breaks so I need to find a way to only call on the function once but return both libraries but I am unsuccessful in doing that.

Comment: Checkout the setup guide here: https://rnmmkv.vercel.app/#/gettingstarted

There is a section that explains how to setup the library alongside reanimated2